# Use fetchrequest predicate to filter out certain coredata items.

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

So I have two entities. Listing and comments. A listing can have multiple associated comments.

```
extension Listing {

    @NSManaged var listingTitle: String?
    @NSManaged var comments: NSSet?
    @NSManaged var listingLatitude: Double
    @NSManaged var listingLongitude: Double
}

extension Comment {

    @NSManaged var comment: String?
    @NSManaged var commentId: String?
    @NSManaged var rating: Int32
    @NSManaged var username: String?
    @NSManaged var listing: Listing?

}
```

Using NSPredicate I can fairly easily filter out listings that are located in say, a particular geographical area as such.

```
// Fetching data from CoreData
            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
            fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "listingLatitude BETWEEN {%f,%f} AND listingLongitude BETWEEN {%f,%f}", (latitude-0.10), (latitude+0.10), (longitude-0.10), (longitude+0.10))
            let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Listing", inManagedObjectContext: self.mainMoc)
            fetchRequest.entity = entity

            fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

            do {
                listings = try self.mainMoc.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [Listing]

            }
```

This works fine, but how do I accomplish filtering out all Listings with comments that has a given a particular rating for instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `comments` is a to-Many relationship, you need to help CoreData work out which of them you are concerned about: ALL, ANY or NONE.  So for example:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY comments.rating > 4")
```

will include only those `Listings` for which ANY of its `Comments` is rated 4 or more, whereas:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ALL comments.rating < 2")
```

will include them only if ALL the `Comments` are rated less than 2.

Comment: Is it possible to chain this with my other NSPredicate somehow? The following seems to throw an error:

fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "listingLatitude BETWEEN {%f,%f} AND listingLongitude BETWEEN {%f,%f}" AND ANY comments.rating >4", (latitude-0.10), (latitude+0.10), (longitude-0.10), (longitude+0.10))

Comment: Also seems to return: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'to-many key not allowed here'

Comment: Nevermind! It totally works. Not sure what I did wrong previously. Thank you!